# Is it possible to install 9.3 Desktop Administrator as a standalone program?

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-server

I have ArcServer 9.3 installed on a server that I use for running scheduled Python geoprocessing scripts.  I have several running, and now I'm trying to schedule one to rec/post, delete and recreate our database versions.  The issue that I'm having is this line of code

```
gp.SetProduct("ArcEditor")
```

Apparently to run the versioning tools, I need to have valid license of ArcEditor or higher availible to the server.  I would really rather not install ArcGIS desktop on my server box, but I'm stuck for a solution.  My main question is, is it possible to install the 9.3 Desktop Adminstrator as a standalone program, then point it at my license manager so that the script can find a license file?  If not, that's fine, any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never actually tested this in an environment where Desktop is not installed, but you might try setting the license server through the system registry. This [KB article](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=33925) describes the registry keys in which these settings are stored. This [blog post](http://www.carlosfemmer.com/post/2008/03/Registry-Setting-Change-for-ESRI-License-%28Network--Single%29.aspx) might also help.

Comment: this should work